# How to Import SQLite data (gathered by an Android device) into either Octave or MatLab?

Tags: sqlite, matlab, signal-processing, octave

I have some data gathered by an Android phone and it is stored in SQLite format in an SQLite file. I would like to play around with this data (analysing it) using either MatLab or Octave. The SQLite data is stored as a file.

I was wondering what commands you would use to import this data into MatLab? To say, put it into a vector or matrix. Do I need any special toolboxes or packages like the Database Package to access the SQL format?

Comment: How complex is the data? Is it just numbers in a table (that you could export to CSV) or is something more complex involved?

Comment: it is mostly just a single table within the file and the table is populated with numbers (but one column has time in hh:mm:ss.ms format). 
I will try the CSV idea (cheers for the idea) for now. I guess I would use the file i/o commands in MatLab? But eventually, I will have stacks of different SQL files and it might get cumbersome to convert each one to CSV.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the [mksqlite](http://mksqlite.berlios.de/mksqlite_eng.html) tool.

I've used it personally, had some issues of getting the correct version for my version of matlab. But after that, no problems. You can even query the database file directly to reduce the amount of data you import into matlab.

Comment: I've had a look at it and it looks pretty good. I am using a linux machine (with limited permissions given to me) and I am wondering whether it is possible to use mksqlite on that?

Comment: Look for 'How can i rebuild mksqlite?' on the documentation page. You only need a compiler and matlab. I had both, used `buildit`, got some warnings and it was installed.

Answer (score 3):

Although *mksqlite* looks nice it is not available for Octave, and may not be suitable as a long-term solution. Exporting the tables to CSV-files is an option, but the importing (into Octave) can be quite slow for larger data sets because of the string-parsing involved.

As an alternative, I ended up writing a small Python script to convert my SQLite table into a MAT file, which is fast to load into either Matlab or Octave. MAT files are platform-neutral binary files, and the method works both for columns with numbers and strings.

```
import sqlite3
import scipy.io

conn = sqlite3.connect('my_data.db')
csr = conn.cursor()
res = csr.execute('SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE')
db_parms = list(map(lambda x: x[0], res.description))

# Remove those variables in db_parms you do not want to export

X = {}
for prm in db_parms:
    csr.execute('SELECT "%s" FROM MY_TABLE' % (prm))
    v = csr.fetchall()
    # v is now a list of 1-tuples
    X[prm] = list(*zip(*v))

scipy.io.savemat('my_data.mat', X)
```